# Bad Allocation error while caching bitmap data in the memory

Tags: c++, memory

I have a C++ app which generates raw bitmap images in runtime and pushes those into temporary std::vector allocating the memory dynamically on each write, which is then used to write those images to file before the program exists.Currently the bitmap size is 1280x720. I am getting "bad allocation" error after frame 650 +- 3 frames.It is pretty clear to me that the reasons for this is not enough RAM memory.That is because if I make smaller size (let'say 300x200) I manage to store all the 950 frames ok.It is strange because my machine has 16gb of RAM.Also in the task manager I see the RAM display has still a lot of free (dark green) space(getting only 5gb in use at most).It utilize like 1/3 of the space only.I am running on Windows 7 64bit 16gb RAM Intel I7 CPU.I am debugging the program in VS2012.Is it possible the OS restricts the dynamic allocation to some arbitrary size?If yes, how can I lift that restriction?

The type of data is bytes (unsigned chars).And yes ,as someone mentioned in the answer below , I compile for 32bit.

Comment: what is the type of your samples? char, int or double?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1280 x 720 x 3 (bytes/pixel) = 2764800 bytes/image = 2.64 MB/image (I'm supposing 24 bpp images here)

2.64 MB/image x 650 images = 1713.87 MB, really near to the dreaded 2 GB boundary. This makes me thing that you are running on a 64 bit OS, but your application is compiled as a 32 bit application without the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` linker flag, thus it has only a 2 GB virtual address space available<sup>1</sup>.

To easily exploit the physical RAM available on your machine you can compile your program as a 64 bit application (thus rendering substantially irrelevant the virtual address space limitations). Other methods are quite a bit more complicated (usually they involve managing "sliding windows" of memory by yourselves).

Another option is to compile your application with the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` linker flag, but you are going to actually get more memory on 32 bit systems launched with the `/3GB` kernel option or on 64 bit systems (respectively, 1 GB more and 2 GB more); also, given that the high bit of the addresses can be set, then you have to be careful in what you do with pointers (subtraction and comparisons can be tricky).

---

1. Actually, 32 bit pointers can address a full 4 GB virtual address space, but the upper half is reserved for the system by default.

Comment: Great!That is probably the problem here.I will try recompile with 64bit version.

Comment: I am compiling a 32 bit app and it does throw a `std::bad_alloc` error just upon reaching the *1GB* boundary (debugging under VS 2015) - instead of 2GB. What can be causing this ? Is the first half reserved ?

Comment: @PinkTurtle: is it a single big allocation?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to but the loading is happening in an object's function called for all instances of the object. Visually, memory usage shows up in "Process Memory" where is raises steady to 1GB then throws an bad alloc error. I am actually pushing data to an instance vector member.

Comment: More pecisely : I am reading a test 200MB plain text .obj file (3d model) and pushing vertex data to it's mesh in a for loop. Nothing like a single huge var instanciation. I'm really pushing vertices 1 by 1.